# Preventing TouchCancel events in Android Cordova Application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

An Android app I'm working on relies on a potentially long series of touchmove events from the user.  Some of these touchmove events don't trigger much computation, but some do.  It seems I am being bitten by [this feature of the Android WebKit](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260732)
 where a touchcancel event will be fired if a touchmove handler does not return within ~200ms.  According to [this response on that bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260732#hc21)

> 1: for mobile-optimized sites (those with width=device-width viewports), you can rely on 
>   always getting uninterrupted touch events.  So touch-heavy sites should be using a mobile 
>   viewport to indicate they're designed to work well on mobile.

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for me.  The afflicted parts of the application are HTML pages with the following viewport setting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, 
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

With that setting I am seeing touchcancel events being fired when a touchmove event takes too long.  I've tried to make the touchmove events faster, but increasing the speed so this issue doesn't come up as often isn't a surefire solution.  Is there any way to prevent the touchcancel events, or at least work around them?

Many thanks!

Comment: this touchcancel thing is driving me nuts :/

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: No I never did find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is facing this issue, [here's a small jQuery extension](https://github.com/andreszs/jquery.events.swipe) that explains how to deal with `pointercancel` and `touchcancel` events.

Basically, try to work with **pointer events** and you will be able to prevent `pointercancel` by simply using the `touch-action` CSS property with a value of `none`.

If you really must use the legacy **touch events** instead, you'll have to implement `event.preventDefault()` in your touchmove events and this will prevent touchcancel from firing, but it will also disable entirely the browser handling of any default action like a pan or click.